# Pass static resource to custom System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

Consider the value converter below. I can easily pass values such as "Red" and "Green" to my converter, but how could I pass a brush defined in XAML?

**How do I bind `FalseBrush` to `MyNiceBrush`?**

```
<local:MyBrushConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" FalseBrush="Red" TrueBrush="Green" />

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyNiceBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#4C7F00" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#A0B529" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

In XAML, I bind my object's property to this converter: `Background="{Binding MyClass.TrueOrFalseProperty, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter} ...`

Here's my converter:

```
public class MyBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return TrueBrush;
        else
            return FalseBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do this via `StaticResource`? `FalseBrush={StaticResource MyNiceBrush}`.

Comment: I've tried that, but I keep getting an exception: "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception."

Comment: Lol... if I put my brush resource above the converter declaration it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<local:MyBrushConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" FalseBrush={StaticResource MyNiceBrush} TrueBrush="Green" />
```